# Index Markdown Files with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, parsing, indexing, markdown, nosql

I am looking for a **Document-Oriented-Database** solution - MongoDB preferred - to index a continuously growing and frequently changing number of (pandoc) **markdown files**.

I read that **MongoDB** has a clean text indexer but I have not worked with MongoDB before and the only thing related which I found was an indexing process of preprocessed HTML. The scenario I am thinking about is: An automatic indexing of the markdown files where the markdown syntax is used to create keys (for example `## FOOO` -> `header2: FOO`) and where the hierarchical structure of the key/value pairs is preserved as they appear in the document.

Is this possible with MongoDB only or do I always need a preprocessing in which I transform the markdown into something like a BSON file and than ingest it into MongoDB?

Comment: I reformulated the question to develope a stronger focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use MongoDB for it? I think [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) is much better fitting for this purpose, it's basically built for indexing texts. However - the same as with MongoDB - you won't get anything automatic and will need to process the document before saving it, if you to improve the precision of finding the documents. The whole document needs to be sent to ElasticSearch as a JSON object, but you can store inside a property also the whole unprocessed markdown text.

I'm not sure about MongoDB full text indices, but ElasticSearch also combines all indexed properties of a document for the full text search. Additionally you can also define the importance of different properties in your index. For instance the title might be more important than the rest of the text, ...